# Is there any way to make a JTextArea in one class respond to JButton clicks in another?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, action, observer-pattern

I need to make the JTextField in my ChatPanel class respond to JButton clicks in my Toolbar class. Is there any way to do this that will scale well if my program gets large? I tried doing this with an Action object, but i'm not sure what I need to do with the object. Here is my code:

```
public class Toolbar extends JPanel {

private JButton helloButton;

public Toolbar() {
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    helloButton = new JButton(new HelloAction("Hello", null));

    add(helloButton);

}


class HelloAction extends AbstractAction {

    public HelloAction(String text, ImageIcon icon) {
        super(text, icon);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //want to print "hello\n" in the JTextArea in ChatPanel
    }
}

}

public class ChatPanel extends JPanel {

private JLabel nameLabel;
private JTextField chatField;
private JTextArea chatArea;
private GridBagConstraints gc;

private static final String NEWLINE = "\n";

public ChatPanel() {
    super(new GridBagLayout());

    //chatArea
    chatArea = new JTextArea(8, 30);
    chatArea.setEditable(false);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(chatArea);
    gc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy = 0;
    add(scrollPane, gc);

    //nameLabel
    nameLabel = new JLabel("Name: ");
    gc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy = 2;
    gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
    gc.weightx = 0.0;
    add(nameLabel, gc);

    //chatField
    chatField = new JTextField(25);
    chatField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String message = chatField.getText() + NEWLINE;
            chatArea.append(message);
            chatField.setText("");
        }

    });
    gc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy = 2;
    gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
    gc.weightx = 0.0;
    add(chatField, gc);



}

}

public class MainFrame {

private static int width = 800;
private static int height = (int) (width * (9.0 / 16));

private JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Main Frame");

public MainFrame() {
    mainFrame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    mainFrame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    mainFrame.pack();
    mainFrame.setResizable(false);

    //Toolbar
    Toolbar toolbar = new Toolbar();

    GridBagConstraints gcToolbar = new GridBagConstraints();
    gcToolbar.gridx = 0;
    gcToolbar.gridy = 0;
    mainFrame.add(toolbar);

    //ChatPanel
    ChatPanel chatPanel = new ChatPanel();
    GridBagConstraints gcChatPanel = new GridBagConstraints();
    gcChatPanel.gridx = 0;
    gcChatPanel.gridy = 2;
    gcChatPanel.gridwidth = 2;
    gcChatPanel.weighty = 1.0;
    gcChatPanel.weightx = 1.0;
    gcChatPanel.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LAST_LINE_START;
    mainFrame.add(chatPanel, gcChatPanel);

    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
}   

}
```

Also, any feedback on what I can improve / what i'm doing wrong is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, but what I would do is respond to the button click from within the class it resides and use some kind observer pattern that would then call a method on the instance of the second class

Comment: I thought I could have a Collection of observers, and notify all of them when a button is clicked. But how can I appropriately tell the observers which button was clicked? For example, what should I do if helloButton is clicked?

Comment: If you don't need to have multiple instances of the ChatPanel, you could either make a static instance variable in the ChatPanel that is set in the constructor or you could change the visibility of your JTextArea to public and make it static. You don't specify this in your question though.

Comment: You mean I should have a reference to one of the components in the other? I read that it doesn't scale well, so I was trying to avoid it.

Comment: @rodit `static == bad` and represents a very good interaction of a bad design

Comment: @AliMustafa A simpler solution would be to allow the `Action` to call a method on your `ChatPanel`, but that's one way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is actually a little larger, but with some clever ideas, ease to overcome...

Essentially, you need some way to communicate with the `ChatPanel` from the `Toolbar`.  There are a number of ways you might achieve this, but if you want flexibility then you should to breaking the requirements down and focusing on the functionality of each section...

1. The tool bar holds "actions"
2. Some of these "actions" add text to something

From here, we need something that can bridge the actions and what ever wants to be updated.

Lets start with a simple contract

```
public interface Outlet {

    public void say(String text);

}
```

All this says is, a implementation of this interface can accept some text.

Next, we need some way to set the text when an action occurs, assuming you're going to want several different actions, something like...

```
public class OutletAction extends AbstractAction {

    private Outlet outlet;
    private String text;

    public OutletAction(Outlet outlet, String text) {
        this.outlet = outlet;
        this.text = text;
    }

    public Outlet getOutlet() {
        return outlet;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        getOutlet().say(getText());
    }
}
```

Will make life easier.  Basically, this allows you to specify the `Outlet` to which the text should be sent and the text to be sent

Now, to make life easier you could set a series of common "word" actions, for example...

```
public class HelloAction extends OutletAction {

    public HelloAction(Outlet outlet) {
        super(outlet, "Hello");
        putValue(Action.NAME, "Hello");
        //putValue(Action.SMALL_ICON, icon);
    }
}
```

Now, you need someway to apply these actions to the `Toolbar`...

```
public class Toolbar extends JPanel {

    public void addAction(Action action) {
        add(new JButton(action));
    }

}
```

Simply adding a `addAction` method which takes care of creating the `JButton` and apply the action to it seems like a simple solution.

Finally, we need to update the `ChatPanel` to implement the `Outlet` `interface`

```
public class ChatPanel extends JPanel implements Outlet {
    //...

    @Override
    public void say(String text) {
        chatArea.append(text + NEWLINE);
    }

}
```

Now, you just need to bind them all together...

```
ChatPanel chatPane = new ChatPanel();

HelloAction action = new HelloAction(chatPane);
Toolbar toolBar = new Toolbar();
toolBar.addAction(action);
//... Add what ever other actions you might like...
```

This demonstrates a principle commonly known as "code to interface (not implementation)", it decouples the code a way that allows you to change the underlying implementation without it effecting the rest of the code.  It also guards you code against unwanted interaction, as the actions can only call the `say` method of the `Outlet` interface ;)

And finally, a runnable example...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                ChatPanel chatPane = new ChatPanel();

                HelloAction action = new HelloAction(chatPane);
                Toolbar toolBar = new Toolbar();
                toolBar.addAction(action);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(toolBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                frame.add(chatPane);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class Toolbar extends JPanel {

        public void addAction(Action action) {
            add(new JButton(action));
        }

    }

    public class OutletAction extends AbstractAction {

        private Outlet outlet;
        private String text;

        public OutletAction(Outlet outlet, String text) {
            this.outlet = outlet;
            this.text = text;
        }

        public Outlet getOutlet() {
            return outlet;
        }

        public String getText() {
            return text;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            getOutlet().say(getText());
        }
    }

    public class HelloAction extends OutletAction {

        public HelloAction(Outlet outlet) {
            super(outlet, "Hello");
            putValue(Action.NAME, "Hello");
            //putValue(Action.SMALL_ICON, icon);
        }
    }

    public interface Outlet {

        public void say(String text);

    }

    public class ChatPanel extends JPanel implements Outlet {

        private JLabel nameLabel;
        private JTextField chatField;
        private JTextArea chatArea;
        private GridBagConstraints gc;

        private static final String NEWLINE = "\n";

        public ChatPanel() {
            super(new GridBagLayout());

            //chatArea
            chatArea = new JTextArea(8, 30);
            chatArea.setEditable(false);
            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(chatArea);
            gc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gc.gridx = 0;
            gc.gridy = 0;
            add(scrollPane, gc);

            //nameLabel
            nameLabel = new JLabel("Name: ");
            gc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gc.gridx = 0;
            gc.gridy = 2;
            gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
            gc.weightx = 0.0;
            add(nameLabel, gc);

            //chatField
            chatField = new JTextField(25);
            chatField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String message = chatField.getText() + NEWLINE;
                    chatArea.append(message);
                    chatField.setText("");
                }

            });
            gc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gc.gridx = 0;
            gc.gridy = 2;
            gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
            gc.weightx = 0.0;
            add(chatField, gc);

        }

        @Override
        public void say(String text) {
            chatArea.append(text + NEWLINE);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, but one question: what if I wanted one multiple components to react to one JButton? Maybe I misunderstood, but it seems that this approach only allows one component per button?

Comment: It does at the moment, what's stopping you from allowing it to have multiple recipients (ActionListeners)

Comment: I don't understand. One OutletAction takes one component as an argument, and the Toolbar creates a new JButton for each OutletAction. But what if I wanted the "Hello"-button to print "Hello" in chatArea, but "Goodbye" in another component? Maybe my thinking is incorrect. I want one component (JButton here) to interact with multiple components in different ways.

Comment: Sorry, trying to get my daughter to sleep. The answer really depends on how all these components know about each other. One approach might be to have a master controller, to which you pass to each component. Each component could then register interest in been notified when an Action is performed, this becomes messy as w all the components are getting bombarded by a bunch of actions they don't want to know about.

Comment: You could follow this idea, but instead of just registering an ActionListener which is notified of EVERY action, you could allow the components to provide the name of the action they are interested in, having the controller filter the actions appropriately. Using a master controller like this is kind of a pain, as you basically need to pass it through a whole bunch of objects which otherwise don't care. You could use a singleton pattern to achieve the same thing,my it without the mess, but it creates its own issues.

Comment: The other question is, what happens when some other component wants to add actions to the toolbar? Do you pass the toolbar to everything just in case? If require, this might suggest that your controller needs to provide the means to add actions as well. Regardless, the controller would need to register itself as a ActionListener for every Action, acting as a central hub and dispatcher